# Powershell: Gett all Calendar-Permissions from each user

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to automate a script that gets all user's Calendar-Permissions for the "anonymous"-Group (All external users) and then saves it into a csv-file. This works so far:

```
<#ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $credential -ShowProgress $true #>
$mbxs = Get-ExoMailbox 
$mbxcalendar = ":\Calendar"

$Permissionuser = "Anonymous"
Foreach($mbx in $mbxs)
{
   
    Get-ExoMailboxFolderPermission -identity "$($mbx.Alias)${mbxcalendar}" -User "Anonymous" | select  Identity, User, {$_.Accessrights} | Export-Csv C:\Users\GBU101\exportcalend.csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force | Out-Null -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
   Write-Host "$($mbx.UserPrincipalname)${mbxCalendar}"
}
```

Now the problem is that I don't want to have the folder permissions, but the actual "Calendar"-Permissions for example:

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "myusers@mydomain.com:\Calendar".
```

How can I add the "@mydomain.com:\Calendar" to every request?

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards,

Gabe

Comment: Try with `-identity "$($mbx.Alias)${mbxcalendar}"`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It almost works, but for it adds a second backslash for some reason... Get-ExoMailboxFolderPermission : An error occurred while processing this request.. {"error":{"code":"NotFound","message":"Error executing request. 
","details":[{"code":"Context","target":"","message":"Ex43C0AC|Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundException|The operation couldn't be performed because 
'username@mydomain:\\Calendar' couldn't be found."}],"innererror":{"message":"Error executing request ... and it doesn't add a backslash when I don't add one...

Comment: Adds a backslash where? What is printed on the screen if you do `Write-Host "'$($mbx.Alias)${mbxCalendar}'"` (instead of `Get-ExoMailBoxPemission...`) inside the loop?

Comment: It adds it here: 'username@mydomain:\\Calendar ...

Comment: So the code you've posted (`$mbxcalendar = "@wingd.com:\Calendar"`) is _not_ the code you're actually running :) Please update your question with the actual code

Comment: Yes, i don't really get why, but it does add a "\" for certain users, others work...i think it's with users where they haven't set any permissions. I picked multiple users where I received this error message and it always showed me that this user did not set a permission for anonymous.

Comment: Here's the complete code again